# Running python unittest on pull request (github actions)

Tags: python, unit-testing, github

I have a folder `Tests` with unittests in python (using the package `unittest`).
How can I execute all the tests in the folder when pushing or creating a pull request with github actions?

I saw guides regarding the module `pytest` but couldn't find any about `unittest`, is it possible to do so with `unittest`?

Comment: Just do the same you would do locally to run the tests on the command line, e.g. something like `python -m unittest discover -s ./tests` instead of calling pytest.